# How do I enforce a Windows Authentication After RDP?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, active-directory, windows-server-2012, ldap

I would like to RDP into Windows server machine and after a successful RDP, I would like to configure my Windows to prompt for login again.

The reason for this requirement is because the RDP connection to the Windows server machine would be carried out by an RDP automation tool and upon reaching the target server machine from the RDP tunnel, the user would need to use their LDAP/Windows AD account to login again to ensure tighter security.

How do I implement this the second layer login once a user successfully RDP into a Windows server machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a GP option. On the server go to `Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Security` under `Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates` and look for the setting: `Always prompt for password upon connection` Set it to `Enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this script after logon

`rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`

[Setting startup script GPO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779329%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)